# Auto Submit Form after 10 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my form to be autosubmitted when user enters the tenth character in an input field.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="Form" action="action.php" method="post">
<input name="htno" type="text" value="" />&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I don't know how to use jQuery or ajax.

Comment: Stackoverflow is no code generator. What have you tried so far, where is your research effort, where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, use an if statement to check the length of the input

```
$('#here').keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == 10) {
        $('#subHere').click();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6E5FX/)

Comment: @NishaReddy just saying thanks is not fair, upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a possible solution:

```
$(function () {
    $('#theText').bind('change keyup', function () {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 10) {
            $('#Form').submit();             
        }
    })

});​
```

(You need to identify the text input as "theText")

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2R6vd/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/8LzRN/1/)

script is

```
$('#htno').keydown(function(){
    var vallenth=$(this).val().length;
    if(vallenth==10){
        alert('l');
        $('#Form').submit();
    }
    });​
```

Comment: vote up requires 15 reputation , i jus have 3 :(

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#htno").keydown(function(){
          if($("#htno").val().length == 10){
                  $('#Form').submit();
                } 
          });
});
```

Comment: please use syntax highlighting (see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score -1):

try -

```
$(#id of the text field).keydown(function(e){
  if($(this).val().length == 10)
    $('#Form').submit()
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

ajax is different. when a form is submitted, it either goes as a HTML request or JS (ajax). HTML will refresh the page. JS wont.